# Convert Colored Image to Gray Scale In Codenameone

Tags: colors, codenameone

Can anyone tell me how to go about converting a RGB Image object to Gray Scale? I know there is a lot of information on how to do this in Java already, but I just wanted to get an answer specific to Codenameone so others can benefit.

I am trying to implement [image binarization using Otsu’s algorithm](http://developer.bostjan-cigan.com/java-image-binarization/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Image.getRGB()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html#getRGB--) then modify the array as explained in this answer:

[Convert Image to Grayscale with array matrix RGB java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497211/convert-image-to-grayscale-with-array-matrix-rgb-java)

Notice that the answer above is a bit over simplistic as it doesn't take into account the correct weight per color channel for proper grayscale effect but this depends on your nitpicking levels.

Then use this version of [createImage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html#createImage-int:A-int-int-) with the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a simplified way (not using matrices) of doing what Shai is hinting, here is some sample code

```
int[] rgb = image.getRGB();
for(int k = 0;k<rgb.length;k++)
{
    if(rgb[k]!=0)
    {
        int r = rgb[k]/256/256;
        rgb[k]=rgb[k]-r*0x10000;
        int g = rgb[k]/256;
        rgb[k]=rgb[k]-g*0x100;
        int b = rgb[k];
        int intensity = (int)Math.round(((r+g+b)/(256.0*3.0))*256);
        rgb[k] = intensity+(intensity*256)+intensity*(256*256);
    }
}
Image grayImage = Image.createImage(rgb,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
```